# TomEE: ignore docBase from being scanned

Tags: tomcat, apache-tomee

I have a `docBase` (alternative docroot) that holds a lot of static content that I don't include in a war file. However, the bootstrap code of TomEE scans the `docBase` directories for jar files and other JavaEE components.  Since the `docBase` includes a  large number of files it takes a very long time to deploy.  I was wondering if there is a flag or parameter I can use to ignore the processing (scanning) of these directories.

I tried to tweak the server.xml file of TomEE but nothing seems to be working.

```xml
        <Context docBase="/large/directory" path="/foo/bar">
          <JarScanner scanClassPath="false" scanAllFiles="false" scanAllDirectories="false" />
          <Parameter name= "org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.IGNORE" value="true"  />
          <Environment name="org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.IGNORE" value="true"  type="java.lang.String" />
        </Context>
```

However, with these changes, the `docBase` is still processed and scanned.

Answer (score 0):

Digging into the source code[1] I found system properties that seem to properly skip `docBase` from being scanned:

```java
    private static boolean isExcludedBySystemProperty(final StandardContext standardContext) {
        String name = standardContext.getName();
        if (name == null) {
            name = standardContext.getPath();
            if (name == null) { // possible ?
                name = "";
            }
        }

        if (name.startsWith("/")) {
            name = name.substring(1);
        }

        final SystemInstance systemInstance = SystemInstance.get();
        return "true".equalsIgnoreCase(systemInstance.getProperty(name + ".tomcat-only", systemInstance.getProperty("tomcat-only", "false")));
    }
```

By passing in system properties -Dfoo/bar.tomcat-only=true seem to do the trick. Open source for the win!

1. https://github.com/apache/tomee/blob/master/tomee/tomee-catalina/src/main/java/org/apache/tomee/catalina/TomcatWebAppBuilder.java

Thanks